# can not open boost header files on 64 bit windows

Tags: c++, boost, waf

I have download boost libraries and ran bootstrap.bat and .\b2 . Trying to run it on 64 bit I m getting these errors

```
C:\cygwin\home\vickey\tunebasket\p2p>python waf build --with-tests --boost-includes="c:\boost_1_48_0" --boost-libs=
"c:\Users\vickey\Downloads\lib64\" --boost-static --boost-mt
```

There are the environment variables

```
Waf: Entering directory `C:\cygwin\home\vickey\tunebasket\p2p\build'
'AR' 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\LIB.exe'
'ARFLAGS' ['/NOLOGO']
'AR_TGT_F' '/OUT:'
'BINDIR' 'C:\\users\\vickey\\appdata\\local\\temp/bin'
'BOOST_VERSION' '1_48'
'CC' ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\CL.exe']
'CCLNK_TGT_F' '/OUT:'
'CC_NAME' 'msvc'
'CC_SRC_F' ''
'CC_TGT_F' ['/FC', '/c', '/Fo']
'CFLAGS' ['/nologo']
'CFLAGS_CONSOLE' ['/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE']
'CFLAGS_CRT_MULTITHREADED' ['/MT']
'CFLAGS_CRT_MULTITHREADED_DBG' ['/MTd']
'CFLAGS_CRT_MULTITHREADED_DLL' ['/MD']
'CFLAGS_CRT_MULTITHREADED_DLL_DBG' ['/MDd']
'CFLAGS_NATIVE' ['/SUBSYSTEM:NATIVE']
'CFLAGS_POSIX' ['/SUBSYSTEM:POSIX']
'CFLAGS_WINDOWS' ['/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS']
'CFLAGS_WINDOWSCE' ['/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWSCE']
'CFLAGS_cshlib' []
'CL' ''
'COMPILER_CC' 'msvc'
'COMPILER_CXX' 'msvc'
'CPPPATH_ST' '/I%s'
'CXX' ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\CL.exe']
'CXXFLAGS' ['/nologo']
'CXXFLAGS_CONSOLE' ['/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE']
'CXXFLAGS_CRT_MULTITHREADED' ['/MT']
'CXXFLAGS_CRT_MULTITHREADED_DBG' ['/MTd']
'CXXFLAGS_CRT_MULTITHREADED_DLL' ['/MD']
'CXXFLAGS_CRT_MULTITHREADED_DLL_DBG' ['/MDd']
'CXXFLAGS_NATIVE' ['/SUBSYSTEM:NATIVE']
'CXXFLAGS_POSIX' ['/SUBSYSTEM:POSIX']
'CXXFLAGS_WINDOWS' ['/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS']
'CXXFLAGS_WINDOWSCE' ['/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWSCE']
'CXXFLAGS_cxxshlib' []
'CXXLNK_TGT_F' '/OUT:'
'CXX_NAME' 'msvc'
'CXX_SRC_F' ''
'CXX_TGT_F' ['/FC', '/c', '/Fo']
'DEFINES' []
'DEFINES_ST' '/D%s'
'DEST_BINFMT' 'pe'
'DEST_OS' 'win32'
'IMPLIB_ST' '/IMPLIB:%s'
'INCLUDES' ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\INCLUDE', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microso
ft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\include']
'INCLUDES_BOOST' 'c:\\boost_1_48_0'
'LIBDIR' 'C:\\users\\vickey\\appdata\\local\\temp/lib'
'LIBPATH' ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\LIB', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SD
Ks\\Windows\\v7.0A\\lib']
'LIBPATH_ST' '/LIBPATH:%s'
'LIB_ST' '%s.lib'
'LINK' 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\LINK.exe'
'LINKFLAGS' ['/NOLOGO', '/MANIFEST']
'LINKFLAGS_cshlib' ['/DLL']
'LINKFLAGS_cstlib' []
'LINKFLAGS_cxxshlib' ['/DLL']
'LINK_CC' 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\LINK.exe'
'LINK_CXX' 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\LINK.exe'
'MSVC_COMPILER' 'msvc'
'MSVC_INSTALLED_VERSIONS' [('msvc 10.0Exp', [('x86', ('x86', (['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10
.0\\Common7\\IDE\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mi
crosoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\Tools', 'C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319', 'C:\\Windows\\Mic
rosoft.NET\\Framework\\v3.5', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\VCPackages', 'C:\\Program
 Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\bin\\NETFX 4.0 Tools', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Wind
ows\\v7.0A\\bin', 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gtk-2.0\\runtime\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin', '
C:\\shortcuts', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim73\\', 'C:\\OSSBuild\\GStreamer\\v0.10.7\\sdk\\bin', 'C:\\OSSBuil
d\\GStreamer\\v0.10.7\\bin', 'C:\\Windows\\system32', 'C:\\Windows', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem', 'C:\\Windows\\S
ystem32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenSSH\\bin', 'c:\\Python27\\', 'C:\\Program Files
(x86)\\GnuWin32\\bin', '', 'C:\\GTK2\\2.0\\bin', 'C:\\cygwin\\bin\\mintty.exe', 'C:\\libglade'], ['C:\\Program File
s (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\INCLUDE', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\incl
ude'], ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\LIB', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\
\Windows\\v7.0A\\lib'])))]), ('msvc 10.0', [('x86', ('x86', (['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.
0\\Common7\\IDE\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mic
rosoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\Tools', 'C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319', 'C:\\Windows\\Micr
osoft.NET\\Framework\\v3.5', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\VCPackages', 'C:\\Program
Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\bin\\NETFX 4.0 Tools', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windo
ws\\v7.0A\\bin', 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gtk-2.0\\runtime\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin', 'C
:\\shortcuts', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim73\\', 'C:\\OSSBuild\\GStreamer\\v0.10.7\\sdk\\bin', 'C:\\OSSBuild
\\GStreamer\\v0.10.7\\bin', 'C:\\Windows\\system32', 'C:\\Windows', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem', 'C:\\Windows\\Sy
stem32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenSSH\\bin', 'c:\\Python27\\', 'C:\\Program Files (
x86)\\GnuWin32\\bin', '', 'C:\\GTK2\\2.0\\bin', 'C:\\cygwin\\bin\\mintty.exe', 'C:\\libglade'], ['C:\\Program Files
 (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\INCLUDE', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\inclu
de'], ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\LIB', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\
Windows\\v7.0A\\lib'])))])]
'MSVC_MANIFEST' True
'MSVC_VERSION' 10.0
'MT' 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\bin\\MT.exe'
'MTFLAGS' ['/NOLOGO']
'PATH' ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\IDE\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsof
t Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\Tools', 'C:\\Windo
ws\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319', 'C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v3.5', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\
\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\VCPackages', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\bin\\NETF
X 4.0 Tools', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\bin', 'c:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\gt
k-2.0\\runtime\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin', 'C:\\shortcuts', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim73\\'
, 'C:\\OSSBuild\\GStreamer\\v0.10.7\\sdk\\bin', 'C:\\OSSBuild\\GStreamer\\v0.10.7\\bin', 'C:\\Windows\\system32', '
C:\\Windows', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\', 'C:\\Program Files
 (x86)\\OpenSSH\\bin', 'c:\\Python27\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuWin32\\bin', '', 'C:\\GTK2\\2.0\\bin', 'C:\\c
ygwin\\bin\\mintty.exe', 'C:\\libglade']
'PREFIX' 'C:\\users\\vickey\\appdata\\local\\temp'
'STLIBPATH_BOOST' ['c:\\Users\\vickey\\Downloads\\lib64']
'STLIBPATH_ST' '/LIBPATH:%s'
'STLIB_BOOST' ['boost_unit_test_framework-vc100-mt-1_48']
'STLIB_ST' 'lib%s.lib'
'WINRC' 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\bin\\RC.exe'
'WINRCFLAGS' []
'WINRC_SRC_F' ''
'WINRC_TGT_F' '/fo'
'cfg_files' ['C:\\cygwin\\home\\vickey\\tunebasket\\p2p\\build\\config.h']
'commonCFlags' ['/EHsc', '/MD']
'commonCxxFlags' ['/EHsc', '/MD']
'commonLinkFlags' []
'cprogram_PATTERN' '%s.exe'
'cshlib_PATTERN' '%s.dll'
'cstlib_PATTERN' 'lib%s.lib'
'cxxprogram_PATTERN' '%s.exe'
'cxxshlib_PATTERN' '%s.dll'
'cxxstlib_PATTERN' 'lib%s.lib'
'define_key' []
'implib_PATTERN' '%s.lib'
'projectDir' 'C:\\\\cygwin\\\\home\\\\vickey\\\\tunebasket\\\\p2p'
```

compilation output

```
dbPath C:\cygwin\home\vickey\tunebasket\p2p\src\Database
dbPath1 C:\cygwin\home\vickey\tunebasket\p2p\src\Database\util
[ 7/16] cxx: src\Repository\Song.cpp -> build\src\Repository\Song.cpp.1.o
[ 9/16] cxx: src\Repository\Songs.cpp -> build\src\Repository\Songs.cpp.2.o
Songs.cpp
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xlocale(323) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler
used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
c:\cygwin\home\vickey\tunebasket\p2p\src\database\vectoriterator.h(4) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file
: 'boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp': No such file or directory
Song.cpp
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xlocale(323) : warning C4530: C++ exception handler
used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
c:\cygwin\home\vickey\tunebasket\p2p\src\database\typedefs.h(4) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boo
st/shared_ptr.hpp': No such file or directory
Waf: Leaving directory `C:\cygwin\home\vickey\tunebasket\p2p\build'
Build failed
 -> task in 'Songs.o' failed (exit status 2):
        {task 40568720: cxx Songs.cpp -> Songs.cpp.2.o}
['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\CL.exe', '/nologo', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\M
icrosoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\INCLUDE', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\include', ''
, '..\\src\\Repository\\Songs.cpp', '/FC', '/c', '/Fo', 'src\\Repository\\Songs.cpp.2.o']
 -> task in 'Song.o' failed (exit status 2):
        {task 40568368: cxx Song.cpp -> Song.cpp.1.o}
['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\BIN\\CL.exe', '/nologo', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\M
icrosoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\INCLUDE', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\include', ''
, '..\\src\\Repository\\Song.cpp', '/FC', '/c', '/Fo', 'src\\Repository\\Song.cpp.1.o']
```

But these header files are present in the the boost home directory. Do boost libraries have to be compiled differently for 64 bit system?

Comment: What's the complete path to the header file that is not found?

Comment: Looks like you are using the Microsoft compiler in combination with Cygwin. I'm not 100% sure, but this might lead to issues with path separators ("/" vs "\").

Comment: @Brady: C:\boost_1_48_0\boost\shared_ptr.hpp

Comment: @FrankSchmitt : yeah I have the source code in the C:\cygwin\home\vickey directory , but I m using command prompt for compiling it.

Comment: Can you also show the compiler command and output.

Comment: @Brady I have included entire execution output now . Are you able to figure out the problem ?

Comment: I was hoping to see if the include paths were correctly set when calling the compiler, but dont see that info. Its most likely one of 2 things: path separators like @FrankSchmitt mentioned, or the `--boost-includes` is not being handled and passed to the compiler correctly.

Comment: okay I will include the environment variables in the the output

Comment: one thing in the environment variable's output that look doubtful is 'DEST_OS' 'win32' .

Answer (score 0):

After having looked at the Environment variables, I see that the `INCLUDES` variable doesnt have the Boost include paths:

```
'INCLUDES' ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\INCLUDE', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\include']
'INCLUDES_BOOST' 'c:\\boost_1_48_0'
```

But the `INCLUDES_BOOST` variable does. I seem to remember that instead it should be `BOOST_INCLUDES`. Check that you're correctly initializing the waf boost tool.

If that doesnt work, try setting the Boost include paths in the normal include paths to see if they are found. If so, then you know its a problem with the waf boost tool, or how its being used. And try executing waf with verbosity set to see what include paths its passing to the compiler.

If that fails, then it may be a problem of path separators as mentioned in previous comments. Here is an example that worries me, notice that both '\' and '/' are being used:

```
'LIBDIR' 'C:\\users\\vickey\\appdata\\local\\temp/lib'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to use use='BOOST' in your task generator declaration, which is why the boost includes weren't added to the compilation line.